# Joint PMF Probability Question!

Tags: probability

I am struggling with this question and I really need some support.

A and B are 2 independent Bernoulli random variables. A has the probability of being 1 is 0.8 and B has the probability of being 1 is 0.4. We create M and N as M = 3A - B and N = A + 2B.
What is the joint PMF of M and N?

I have created tables with the value of M and N, corresponding with the value of A and B. However, I don't know how to find the joint PMF of these two. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

If your table contains all the non-zero probability events, which will be $\{(M,N)=(0,0),~~(M,N)=(-1,2),~~(M,N)=(3,1),~~(M,N)=(2,3)\}$ then this is the joint probability distribution (equivalently called the joint mass function) for $M$ and $N$.

Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution